# Excel VBA: sum chart range

Tags: vba, excel

Macro below works fine, but i want for range F23 sum number from range D2.

```
Sub Macro1()
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graph").Activate
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$E$13:$F$23")
End Sub
```

So if in cell D2 is number 87, then instead $F$23 will be $F$110. Always sum 23 with value in D2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Source:=Range("Sheet1!$E$13:$F$" & (23 + Range("D2").Value))
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to modify the Range String "Sheet1!$E$13:$F$23". You may try:

```
Sub Macro1()
  ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graph").Activate

  Dim valD2 As Integer
  valD2 = CInt(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Value)
  Dim rangeStr As String
  rangeStr = "Sheet1!$E$13:$F$" & CStr(valD2 + 23)

  ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(rangeStr)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
Source:=Range("Sheet1!$E$13:$F$13").Resize(10 + Range("D2").Value)
```